# Is there an equivalent term to 'imagery' in context with maps and cartography?

Tags: terminology

Is there an equivalent term to *imagery* in context with maps or cartography?
*Mappery* seems not to exist. (I'm from Germany, and some miles away from being a native-English speaker)

To explain that a little bit more: *Imagery* can be used very generalizing, comprising all material that stems from '(optical) sensoring' no matter whether satellite-, air- or home-cam-borne, no matter whether raw material or say atmospherically corrected. And, the term is not even restricted to the material, rather more comprising techniques, methods, the production and/or the processing of images as well.

In terms of this generalizing meaning of *Imagery*, I am looking for an equivalent for everything that is analogously related to all, maps, cartography, methods, processing ...

Comment: I would think that "Cartography" is that term but as another non native English speaker I could miss some restriction on the definition of "cartography". "geomatics" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geomatics) could be another candidate but it feel a bit restricted to the digital aspect...

Comment: Coul "Mapping" or "Map-making" not also fit the description? My thinking there is based on the way I use imagery, generic. When chatting to people not in my field, I refer to myself as a Cartographer, but have also used Mapping and Map-making in the descriptions used.

Comment: _"And, the term is not even restricted to the material, rather more comprising techniques, methods, the production and/or the processing of images as well."_ I don't think 'Imagery' is widely/commonly used out of the image **data** context.